# Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CAR(ID) : While calling the POST service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

CarController.java

```
package com.mytaxi.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mytaxi.controller.mapper.CarMapper;
import com.mytaxi.datatransferobject.CarDTO;
import com.mytaxi.datatransferobject.CarDTO;
import com.mytaxi.domainobject.CarDO;
import com.mytaxi.domainvalue.Type;
import com.mytaxi.exception.ConstraintsViolationException;
import com.mytaxi.exception.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.mytaxi.service.car.CarService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/cars")
public class CarController
{

private final CarService carService;

@Autowired
public CarController(final CarService carService)
{
    this.carService = carService;
}


@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public CarDTO createCar(@Valid @RequestBody CarDTO carDTO) throws ConstraintsViolationException
{
    CarDO carDO = CarMapper.makeCarDO(carDTO);
    carDTO = CarMapper.makeCarDTO(carDO);
    carService.create(carDO);
    return carDTO;
}
```

}

CarDO.java

```
package com.mytaxi.domainobject;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import com.mytaxi.domainvalue.Type;

@Entity
@Table(
    name = "car",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uc_licensePlate", columnNames = {"licensePlate"})
)
public class CarDO
{
@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Type manufacturer;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String licensePlate;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer seatCount;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String engineType;

@Column(nullable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="yes_no")
private Boolean convertible;

@Column
@Max(5)
private Integer rating;

@Column(nullable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="yes_no")
private Boolean isFunctioning = true;

@Column(nullable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="yes_no")
private Boolean isBooked = false;


public Boolean getIsFunctioning()
{
    return isFunctioning;
}

public void setIsFunctioning(Boolean isFunctioning)
{
    this.isFunctioning = isFunctioning;
}

public CarDO(Type manufacturer, String licensePlate, Integer seatCount, 
    String engineType, Boolean convertible)
{
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    this.seatCount = seatCount;
    this.engineType = engineType;
    this.convertible = convertible;
}

public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public Type getManufacturer()
{
    return manufacturer;
}

public void setManufacturer(Type manufacturer)
{
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

public String getLicensePlate()
{
    return licensePlate;
}

public void setLicensePlate(String licensePlate)
{
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
}

public Integer getSeatCount()
{
    return seatCount;
}

public void setSeatCount(Integer seatCount)
{
    this.seatCount = seatCount;
}

public String getEngineType()
{
    return engineType;
}

public void setEngineType(String engineType)
{
    this.engineType = engineType;
}

public Boolean getConvertible()
{
    return convertible;
}

public void setConvertible(Boolean convertible)
{
    this.convertible = convertible;
}

public Integer getRating()
{
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(Integer rating)
{
    this.rating = rating;
}
```

}

CarDTO.java

```
package com.mytaxi.datatransferobject;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.mytaxi.domainvalue.Type;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CarDTO

{
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "license plate can not be null!")
private String licensePlate;

@NotNull(message = "cartype can not be null!")
private Type carType;

@NotNull(message = "seatCount can not be null!")
private Integer seatCount;

@NotNull(message = "engineType can not be null!")
private String engineType;

private Boolean convertible;


private CarDTO()
{
}


public CarDTO(Long id, String licensePlate, Type carType, Integer seatCount, String engineType, Boolean convertible)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    this.carType = carType;
    this.seatCount = seatCount;
    this.engineType = engineType;
    this.convertible = convertible;
}


public static CarDTOBuilder newBuilder()
{
    return new CarDTOBuilder();
}


@JsonProperty
public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}


public String getLicensePlate()
{
    return licensePlate;
}


public Type getCarType()
{
    return carType;
}


public Integer getSeatCount()
{
    return seatCount;
}


public String getEngineType()
{
    return engineType;
}


public Boolean getConvertible()
{
    return convertible;
}

public static class CarDTOBuilder
{
    private Long id;
    private String licensePlate;
    private Type carType;
    private Integer seatCount;
    private String engineType;
    private Boolean convertible;


    public CarDTOBuilder setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }


    public CarDTOBuilder licensePlate(String licensePlate)
    {
        this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
        return this;
    }


    public CarDTOBuilder setLicensePlate(String licensePlate)
    {
        this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
        return this;
    }


    public CarDTOBuilder setCarType(Type carType)
    {
        this.carType = carType;
        return this;
    }


    public CarDTOBuilder setSeatCount(Integer seatCount)
    {
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
        return this;
    }


    public CarDTOBuilder setEngineType(String engineType)
    {
        this.engineType = engineType;
        return this;
    }


    public CarDTOBuilder setConvertible(Boolean convertible)
    {
        this.convertible = convertible;
        return this;
    }

    public CarDTO createCarDTO()
    {
        return new CarDTO(id, licensePlate, carType, seatCount, engineType, convertible);

    }
}
```

}

CarMapper.java

```
package com.mytaxi.controller.mapper;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.mytaxi.datatransferobject.CarDTO;
import com.mytaxi.domainobject.CarDO;

public class CarMapper
{
    public static CarDO makeCarDO(CarDTO carDTO)
    {
        return new CarDO(carDTO.getCarType(), carDTO.getLicensePlate(),
            carDTO.getSeatCount(), carDTO.getEngineType(), carDTO.getConvertible());
    }

    public static CarDTO makeCarDTO(CarDO carDO)
    {  
        CarDTO.CarDTOBuilder carDTOBuilder = CarDTO.newBuilder()
            .setId(carDO.getId())
            .setCarType(carDO.getManufacturer())
            .licensePlate(carDO.getLicensePlate())
            .setSeatCount(carDO.getSeatCount())
            .setEngineType(carDO.getEngineType())
            .setConvertible(carDO.getConvertible());

        return carDTOBuilder.createCarDTO();
    }


    public static List<CarDTO> makeCarDTOList(Collection<CarDO> cars)
    {
        return cars.stream()
            .map(CarMapper::makeCarDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

CarService.java

```
    package com.mytaxi.service.car;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.mytaxi.domainobject.CarDO;
    import com.mytaxi.domainvalue.Type;
    import com.mytaxi.exception.ConstraintsViolationException;
    import com.mytaxi.exception.EntityNotFoundException;

    public interface CarService
    {


        CarDO create(CarDO carDO) throws ConstraintsViolationException;


    }
```

DefaultCarService.java

```
 @Override
    public CarDO create(CarDO carDO) throws ConstraintsViolationException
    {
        CarDO car;
        try
        {
            car = carRepository.save(carDO);
        }
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e)
        {
            LOG.warn("ConstraintsViolationException while creating a driver: {}", carDO, e.getCause());
            throw new ConstraintsViolationException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return car;
    }
```

CarRepository.java

```
package com.mytaxi.dataaccessobject;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.mytaxi.domainobject.CarDO;
import com.mytaxi.domainvalue.Type;


public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<CarDO, Long>
{

    List<CarDO> findByIsFunctioning(Boolean isFunctioning);

    CarDO findByLicensePlate(String licensePlate);

    List<CarDO> findByManufacturer(Type type);
}
```

When I hit the RESTAPI post service, I get the below exception.

Unique index or primary key violation: 
aused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CAR(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into car (convertible, engine_type, is_booked, is_functioning, license_plate, manufacturer, rating, seat_count, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex.add(MVPrimaryIndex.java:123) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:732) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:182) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:134) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 93 common frames omitted"PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CAR(ID) :

Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Are you using H2 Database?

Comment: Yes, I found the answer too.

Comment: @SanghamitraPadhy since you've found the answer, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 8):

I was encountering the same problem for an `@Entity` class. My **data.sql** ids were conflicting with the auto-generated ids from H2.
My solution was to change:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

to

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

This way I could keep my **data.sql** file.
The javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html) indicates that `GenerationType.IDENTITY` "Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column."

Answer (score 2):

It was generating the sequence from 1, since there were already 3 values in the database which was inserted manually while initializing the application, modifying the auto generated sequences solved the issue.

Comment: But how did you modify it?

Comment: So, how did you resolve the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably given by the fact that you already are initializing data, either through a data.sql file, or CommandLineRunner.

Therefore, if you have

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Spring Data JPA automatically tries to set ID from 1 and then autoincrements of 1 for every new entry. If you already have some entries which start with ID 1 that is the problem (there is a conflict of ids).

You should either remove the data inserted if you want to keep things simple, or you should use other methods for generating the id, for example uuid see here https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

@Eenvincible, if you created a data.sql to populate the data, you need to delete those.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an Answer to the Question, but seems to be response to a comment on another Answer instead. Please see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers on Stack Overflow work. Please wait until you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to leave a [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)